# Samsung SmartTV emulator from eclipse

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

> I have configured emulator section in Samsung SmartTV sdk(eclipse),
>   but whenever I am trying to run a project in SamsungTVEmulator, it is
>   giving me the error i.e. could not find the simulator. I am using mac
>   machine.

Now Samsung is supporting Tizen and simulator and emulator both are present for development on mac machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, no emulator available on mac version now. Samsung claims that they will support soon.

At this stage, only window machine supports emulator.

To use emulator on window, you need the following steps which are missing on mac.

1. Open the connection explorer
2. Turn on the emulator manager
3. Create a emulator and then open.
4. Right click the project and Run as the emulator

PS. emulator is different from simulator. I will say simulator is more likely a browser, it doesn't look like TV and not reliable.

Comment: Thanks alan. But I am able to run emulator in virtual box on my mac machine and also able to run the Samsung SmartTV app. but the problem is I am not able to launch it from sdk(eclipse.).

Comment: SDK Emulator Image for Virtual Box can be downloaded from the following link. http://www.samsungdforum.com/Devtools/SdkDownload

Comment: Sorry, i think you are talking about tizen one....normally i won't use eclipse.i will use sublime and restart the virtualbox...the eclipse one is not well functional...